# Having trouble with updatePixels() in a Java app using Processing libraries

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to write a simple game in Java that uses Processing to render graphics. However, I'm having trouble rendering any changes using updatePixels(). I can successfully set the background color and draw basic 2d shapes, but I get nothing from editing the pixels[] variable, or from using set(x, y, color).

This is my (abridged) code:

```
import processing.core.*;

public class GameController extends PApplet {
  private int width, height;

  private final static String RENDER_MODE = PConstants.P2D; //JAVA2D;

  public GameController(int width, int height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height - this.getBounds().y;
  }

  @Override
  public void setup() {
    this.size(this.width, this.height, RENDER_MODE);
    this.background(0);
  }

  @Override
  public void draw() {
    this.ellipse(50, 50, 100, 10);

    this.loadPixels();
    for (int p : this.pixels) {
      p = this.color(255, 0, 0);
    }
    this.updatePixels();
  }
}
```

When I init() this class, I get a white ellipse on a black screen, not a screen of red pixels (which is what I'm expecting).
The pixels[] array is definitely there, as I've printed it out, and I'm getting no errors.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
p = this.color(255, 0, 0);
```

only changes the local variable `p`, which contained a copy if the pixel value.

What you want is to modify the values inside the `pixels` array, as in:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < pixels.length ; i++) {
    pixels[i] = color(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Actually the code you've written is equivalent to Java's for-each function. I think the problem is something more subtle than that. I've also tried modifying individual pixels by index to no avail.

Comment: @Fecal Brunch: no, that's not equivalent, p isn't a reference to a pixel, it is an int. Try the given code.

Comment: @PhiLho Thanks for having a look. I did try this, just in case, and it didn't work. I've also tried things like "pixels[5] = color(255, 0, 0)" to change individuals. I'm fairly certain it's nothing to do with the loop. In regards to why for-each is equivalent, note that "pixels[]" is actually an int array, whose pixels are stored as hexadecimal RGB values. ie. "PApplet.color(255, 0, 0)" will return "0xFF000000" (the last two zeros being the alpha channel).
Just for clarification on for-each equivalency: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html

Comment: Ah, I just tried it again, and now it's working. Awesome. But why didn't for each work?

Comment: Hm, okay, this was right, but when I changed it it nothing happened. The problem I was having was actually somewhere else in the code. Silly me. Thanks guys.